# Read base class xml attribute from custom widget constructor?

Tags: android

I have a class derived from a standard library widget, how can I read one of the base class' xml attributes in the constructor? For example, how would I get the value of "android:layout_height" in the following?:

```
class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        int layoutHeightParamFromXmlAttributes = ?;
    }
}
```

I'm interested in reading other "android:x" attributes in this way, this is just an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

In your widget constructor.
If you get custom attribute then try this.

```
    if (attrs != null) {
                TypedArray attributeArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.CustomTextView);
                //for font
                String fontName = attributeArray.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_font_name);
}
```

And if you get default property like height and width then try this:

```
 int width=attributeArray.getLayoutDimension(0,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 int height = attributeArray.getLayoutDimension(1,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);//index is based on your xml file
```

Define style in `attrs.xml` file

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
    <attr name="font_name" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

In your layout file add this:

```
 <com.package.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/customFTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:font_name="OpenSans-Regular.ttf"
                android:gravity="center"/>
```

Hope this explanation helps you. :)